# Disable everything but a hidden command for root access

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, root, hardening

linux security and root access question....

I'm setting up a server that has a validator node running on it for a blockchain. I was trying to harden the security of my server. I set up ufw for all ports but those necessary for the node to operate. I set up 2FA, SSH with ed25519, and then I was spending time trying to figure out, if for some crazy reason someone got in... how could I stop someone from using `systemctl` or `poweroff` with `sudo` privilages. The goal is maximize uptime and remain in sync with the other nodes at all times.

Anyways, I started blocking `bash` commands for the user account that allows SSH and blocked SSH to `root`. Then I blocked a few more commands and thought, what if someone could find their way around this? So, I just started blocking too many things lol. Even though I disabled `sudo` for the user and blocked a number of commands the user could still use `systemctl` and `stop` the `service` for the node. Eventually I found this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822) on how to only allow a few commands for a user.

I ended up removing all of the commands from the user and symlinked the su command and renamed it to a random command that only I know. All of the other commands done by the user respond with

`-rbash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: restricted: cannot specify /' in command names`

I took away `bash history` and `bash autocomplete/tab completion`. Now the only thing you can do is guess commands that will get you to the point where you still have to get past my `root` password.

Anyways, I'm saying all of this because I have always heard best security practices involve "disabling root". Sometimes I see it as just disable root SSH, which i already have done, but sometimes i read it like disable the root account. Some say disable the password and try to divvy it up with `sudo` privileges so it's more traceable to individual users.

In my case I need to preserve root access in some way but I basically hid everything within the root user. So, if anyone gets access to root it's over. But, it's behind 2FA, SSH, and an unknown command that just gets to where you can try a password to access root.

Am I thinking about this "disable root for security" all wrong and I should disable it completely or does it make sense what I've done so far?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your description makes it likely that we are facing an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here; you may want to consider taking the problem over to [Cybersecurity SE](https://security.stackexchange.com) for advice on an effective way to counter your threat model.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should probably be asked on Security SE.